# MySQLi Matching ID from different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Basically, I'm making a table that outputs people that have been banned. So far, I have everything done with MySQLi, just instead of showing the actual name it shows the player ID. I'm having trouble with this because the players ID is stored in a seperate table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy6G9.png

This picture is the structure of the main table, notice player_id and creator_id? What I have to do is match the ID and replace the number with the row "name" accordingly from the other table shown below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm3Fg.png

If you could help me out, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: i answered this once already, you need to link the tables together using a foreign key.  `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = $id);` would be an example of that.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: You don't need a subquery, @Edward, just a join on id = player_id.

Comment: @Edward: use JOINs in this kind of situation, MySQL handles it way better (and faster) than nested queries.

Comment: Point taken. I just thought it was easier to make sense of as a beginner.

Comment: @Edward Alright I did that, now there's no value...
I have this as my code for that
echo'<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';

Comment: Current code: http://pastebin.com/9EXxb1vK

You can view it live at http://auracraft.net/bans/bans.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will just show you the names of the banned players:

```
SELECT name FROM banned_table INNER JOIN name_table ON player_id=name_table.id
```

Of course you would need to change `banned_table` and `name_table` to the actual tablenames in your DB.

UPDATE: 
From the comments below this is the solution for the OP

```
SELECT b.*,n.name as player, n2.name as admin FROM banhammer_bans b 
JOIN name_table n ON b.player_id=n.id 
JOIN name_table n2 ON b.creator_id=n2.id
ORDER BY b.created_at DESC
```

And change the display code:

```
echo'<td>' . $row['player_id'] . '</td>';
echo'<td>' . $row['creator_id'] . '</td>';
```

To Be:

```
echo'<td>' . $row['player'] . '</td>';
echo'<td>' . $row['admin'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: This did not work either :(

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? error? no names? How about: `SELECT b.*,n.name FROM banhammer_bans b INNER JOIN name_table n ON b.player_id=n.id ORDER BY b.created_at DESC` again substituting the actual name of the `name_table`

Comment: ^ That worked! :) could you please help me incorporate the "Banned by" part? http://auracraft.net/bans/bans.php

Comment: Updated to add the names of the `creator_id` as well. If my answer worked for you, please accept it for future reference.

Comment: thank you so much, works great!

An explanation behind what the query is would help me for future references though :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA, TableB
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id = TableB.player_id
```

Comment: Did not work. I'll post my current code on pastebin